# Swap multiple images on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, swap

What i would like to do is to show the products other versions of images on mousemove from left to right. Here's the simple html example:

```
    <article>
      <figure data-imageList="image2.jpg,image3.jpg,image4.jpg">
        <img data-src="main-image.jpg" src="main-image.jpg">
      </figure>
    </article>
```

As you can see at html, the images src will be change from the data-imageList. When user mouseout from the article, the main-image.jpg will appear again. This will the default image. The function should be trigger when user only move his mouse from left to right on the current article. The other list items shouldn't be affected from the mousemove. Maybe, i should create a unique id or use the "each function" to do that. I couldn't solve that problem either anyway...

Could someone help me to solve that problem. I am really bad at javascript.

Thank you!

Comment: Here is an example site for what i really want (Rollover on the product images) http://bit.ly/1DkhVoH

Comment: Just add this here as to avoid too many comments below my answer - you can change $images = $("figure").data("imageList") into $("figure").data("imagelist") in case you already have too many data-attributes named data-imageList on your live site; retrieving with $.data() will lowercase the name of the attribute. Though it's not in the jquery-api it's mentioned here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9066 (short: it was a bug that camelcased attribute-names weren't retrievable but they fixed it). Already tested on the fiddle with your original attribute name, lowercase will work.

Comment: Could you paste the figure with the data-attribute and the jquery-data query for this in your question or provide a link to the site in question? Just got the automatic notification to avoid too many comments and the chat-suggestion, but maybe it's just a minor issue cleared in 2 more sentences as the fiddle is working.

Comment: the html of this page is broken, the sourcecode stops at line 238 at <img src="http://placehold.it/230x383&text=IMG1" data-original="http://placehold.it/230x383&text=IMG1" width= . Now it stops at line 285 (closing a-tag missing). at least some lines more than previously.. :)

Comment: That url is ok, but there is not class imageHolder anywhere, so the script won't work. Also got a notification here to move this into chat as it's too many comments. Would that be ok? Guess it'll just take some minutes to get if fixed.

Comment: @matthias_h by the way, i've changed some names and classes to get it work so don't mention the names. One thing i've found is changing the $images = $("figure").data("photolist"); from $images = $("figure").data("photolist"); to $images = $(".someClass").data("photolist"); is solve the problem but the mouseout function is not working. Also that affects all other product images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61447/discussion-between-meg-ann-and-matthias-h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/zgnd9w90/1/) with some dummy-images as data-attribute and following jQuery:

```
    $("img").mousemove(function (event) {
    var xPos = event.pageX;
    $images = $("figure").data("imageList");
    var array = $images.split(',');
    if (xPos > 40) {
        $("img").attr("src", array[0]);
    }
    if (xPos > 65) {
        $("img").attr("src", array[1]);
    }
    if (xPos > 85) {
        $("img").attr("src", array[2]);
    }

});
$("img").mouseout(function () {
    $("img").attr("src", $("img").data("src"));
});
```

For demonstration just small images. Could be calculated properly according to the actual image size when the images should be swapped, but for demo just hardcoded the values.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Update: As further requested the same example for responsive: [Change responsive image](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/2f2tth47/)

```
$(".imageHolder").mousemove(function (event) {
    var xPos = event.pageX,
        imgPos = $(".imageHolder").offset().left,
        imgWidth = $(".imageHolder").width();
    var change1 = imgPos,
        change2 = imgPos + imgWidth / 3,
        change3 = imgPos + 2 * imgWidth / 3;
    $images = $("figure").data("imageList");

    var array = $images.split(',');
    if (xPos > change1) {
        $("img").attr("src", array[0]);
    }
    if (xPos > change2) {
        $("img").attr("src", array[1]);
    }
    if (xPos > change3) {
        $("img").attr("src", array[2]);
    }


});
$("img").mouseout(function () {
    $("img").attr("src", $("img").data("src"));
});
```

CSS:

```
figure {
    width:100%;
    max-width:200px;
}
img {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

I also added class `imageHolder` to the image (not necessary but too used to work with classes instead of just applying to elements) and left the console log messages in the Fiddle so it's easier to check the calculated width and positions.
Another minor adjustment in provided example is to change the name of the data-attribute from `data-imageList` to `data-image-list`, also of just being used to it. Reason is the naming convention that every hyphened `data-` attribute will be retrieved minus the hyphen and camelcased (the first letter after the hyphen), so data-image-list will be retrieved as $.data("imageList"). Additional reference for this here: [W3C - The "data-"-attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) 
If the name of the used data-attribute **is** already camelCased, then it's retrievable lowercased: `data-imageList="value1, value2, valu3"` -> `$.data("imagelist")`. Though not mentioned in the jQuery-api, description e.g. here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9066

Comment: This is cool but the design is responsive. So the image width varies by resolution. Can you show me an for a responsive image?

Comment: @MegAnn Glad you like it as I was just about to increase the image size (I just noticed that changing the img on mousemove was only visible in case of moving the mouse very slow). Re responsive - shouldn't be too much of an issue, as it's possible to get the actual img-width / width of the img-container and set the steps for changing the img accordingly. Will add a 2nd fiddle in some minutes.

Comment: @MegAnn Just updated answer with 2nd Fiddle to responsive example.

Comment: This is awesome! I've a small issue though. When i mouseover on my live design, it's not working. Here is the error msg i got; "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"  The detail of the message is: (anonymous function) (index):278m.event.dispatch jquery.js:3r.handle

Comment: @MegAnn Maybe that's only related to your live site and my renaming of the data-attribute I just mentioned in my minor answer-upate 1 min ago. I renamed your data-attribute and so you don't get it's value in case you just applied my example. Is that possible..?

Comment: Nope. Copy-paste everything you wrote in the 2nd Fiddle. I've also changed the Jquery version but nothing change.

Comment: This no longer works in Safari, think it might be a bug in the latest version 10.0 but Safari is downloading the attr at every move of the mouse. Check your Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/zgnd9w90/1/ - if anyone can come up with a solution please let me know !

Comment: @IanTearle Thanks for sharing this info. Will try if I can find a solution or, in case there's already a solution provided on SO, update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `div` and place and `img` control inside it. Now with `onmouseover` and `e.PageX` find the `change in width` and the `width` of `div` and then using `if-else` change the `src` attribute of `img`. Finally using `onmouseleave` change the `src` of `img` to default.

```js
var prevX = 0;
$('div').mousemove(function(e) {
 var direc = (prevX >= e.pageX ? "left" : "right");
    if(direc==="right"){
        if(e.pageX>100){
        $("#img").attr("src", "http://dummyimage.com/200x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+2");
        }
        else
        {
        $("#img").attr("src", "http://dummyimage.com/200x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+3");
        }
    }
    prevX = e.pageX;
});

$( 'div' ).mouseleave(function() {
$("#img").attr("src", "http://dummyimage.com/200x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+1");
});
```

```css
div
{
    height:300px;
    width:200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <img id="img" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+1">
</div>
```