# How do I randomly change images source on mousemove?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to randomly change the source of an image when a user moves their mouse about 100px inside a div. I only want to update the source, not stack images on top of each other or set them to display:block or display:none etc.

[Here is an example](http://www.christopherhalldesign.com/) When the website has loaded, be sure to click to see the example.

So far I have the below HTML

```
<div class="header-image-inner">
    <img src="img/image-01.png" alt="" />
</div>

$(".header-image-inner").mousemove(function (event) {
    $(".header-image-inner img").attr('src', 'image-02.png');
    $(".header-image-inner img").attr('src', 'image-03.png');
    $(".header-image-inner img").attr('src', 'image-04.png');
});
```

Comment: Wheres the question sign, indicating that this is indeed a question? May have a look at `event.target`, especially its `src` property...

Comment: Ive added a How do and one of these '?' Does this help

Comment: It was rather a slight hint that your question is lacking a specific problem, has not included research effort and is therefore to broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap multiple images on mousemove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896664/swap-multiple-images-on-mousemove)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a working demo of the same.
[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/farhan2056/n3zhvey1/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="header-image-inner">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1492799808351-30d7d3955cac?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=74696345f3ca20d8a46bf6d692b78c53&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var images = [
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518127864129-8d0834d765bc?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5acdfad29e7fef07a86e6174e3b1d73c&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518065336951-d16c043900d6?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=05f800ba4e6c18a40a8f7cf12cdd2c35&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1492799808351-30d7d3955cac?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=74696345f3ca20d8a46bf6d692b78c53&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
    ];
    var currentX = 0, currentY = 0;
    $('.header-image-inner').mousemove(function(e){
        if(Math.abs(currentX-e.pageX) > 50 || Math.abs(currentY-e.pageY) > 50){
            currentX = e.pageX;
            currentY = e.pageY;
            $('.header-image-inner img').attr('src',images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)]);
        }
    })
})
```

The code is self-explanatory. I hope it helps.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much for helping. I couldn't code this but looking at it I can see how how it may work etc. Thank you :)